# mvn spring-boot:build-image doesn't save image in docker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I tried to create a docker image with this command

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image
```

and it shows a successful result but when I search my docker images I can't find it. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
╰─⠠⠵ mvn spring-boot:build-image   
...
O]     [creator]     Saving docker.io/library/spring-service:0.0.16-SNAPSHOT...
[INFO]     [creator]     *** Images (f28300653802):
[INFO]     [creator]           docker.io/library/spring-service:0.0.16-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/syft:syft'
[INFO]     [creator]     Reusing cache layer 'cache.sbom'
[INFO] 
[INFO] Successfully built image 'docker.io/library/spring-service:0.0.16-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  28.784 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-01T18:19:01+04:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
╰─⠠⠵ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                      TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
mariadb                         <none>    01d138caf7d0   8 days ago     384MB
grafana/grafana                 latest    b6ea013786be   9 days ago     299MB
redis                           <none>    dc7b40a0b05d   9 days ago     117MB
bitnami/zookeeper               latest    dd7f87e04f7b   10 days ago    521MB
bitnami/kafka                   latest    c01437a78c04   12 days ago    664MB
prom/prometheus                 latest    d3167094f2ef   2 weeks ago    215MB
mariadb                         latest    40b966d7252f   4 weeks ago    383MB
redis                           latest    3e42dd4e79c7   4 weeks ago    117MB
emqx/emqx                       latest    42418de7f6c3   4 weeks ago    148MB
portainer/portainer-ce          2.11.1    ed396c816a75   6 months ago   280MB
```

Comment: That's not possible. Please try docker image ls -a

Comment: It will be great if you also share your pom.xml. Specifically, the part related to spring-boot plugin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about, the creation of your Docker images works correctly. You're just using a bit wrong command to search for newly created images.

The default «ls» command hides intermediate images. You may check the details here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_ls/

This one should display your newly created Docker image:

```
  docker image ls --all
```

**Updated:**
I'm using the Spring Boot Maven plugin with such configuration, which performs the build of Docker images when executing `mvn install` or `mvn package` commands:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-image</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It works correctly. I'm using the `2.7.3` version of the Spring Boot and Maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this command gives me the same response and when I try to run the image docker says the image doesn't exist

Comment: @ImanAhrari This looks a bit unexpected. Could you please share your source code, so I can reproduce it on my side to check what is wrong?

Comment: I have added an update to my answer with my configuration of the Spring Boot Maven plugin, which works correctly for me. Please try to use it on your end.